# Does it make sense to use .apply( ) and pass the same instance as context?

Tags: javascript, function, call, execution, apply

I'm reading Javascript Web Applications, from O'Reilly. At various points in the book, the author uses something along the following:

```
instance.init.apply(instance, arguments);
```

Does this make any sense? Isn't this exactly the same as:

```
instance.init(arguments);
```

.call() and .apply() are used to manually set the execution context of a function. Why should I use them when I'm intending to use the original execution context anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is that `arguments` is an array-like object. Doing ...

```
instance.init(arguments);
```

... passes one argument, which is an array-like object containing certain arguments. On the other hand, doing ...

```
instance.init.apply(instance, arguments);
```

... will pass the array-like object *as separate arguments*. It is true that setting `instance` is kind of useless because you already wrote it, but if using `.apply` you simply need to set the `this` value as well.

A quick example of the difference:

```
function log(a, b, c) {
    console.log(a, b, c);
}

function log2() {
    log.apply(null, arguments); // `this` value is not meaningful here,
                                // it's about `arguments`
}

function log3() {
    log(arguments);
}

log(1, 2, 3);  // logs:  1, 2, 3

log2(1, 2, 3); // logs:  1, 2, 3

log3(1, 2, 3); // logs:  <Arguments>, undefined, undefined
               //        where <Arguments> contains the values 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, but log2(1, 2, 3) also logs "1, 2, 3".

Comment: Ok, so to clarify: The only difference really is that I can call a function and programatically shift the arguments passed to where I am now to another function, without transforming them into an array-like structure?  ---edit--- yeah, got it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Using apply() in that example insures that 'this' === instance, instead of DOMWindow if instance.init() is executed from another function/expression.

```
var x = function(){ debugger; },
    y = function(){ x.apply(x, arguments); },
    z = function() { x(arguments); };

y("abc", true, []); // this === x
z("abc", true, []); // this === DOMWindow
```

It's simply specifying context.

Comment: Although .apply and .call are context modifiers, i believe that in this particular case, the main purpose of .apply is to unsure a correct passage of arguments as stated in the previous answer. Although as a side effect it really ensures the correct context like you said.

Comment: True, but if that's the case it's a misuse of apply() due to laziness.

Comment: ok... how you would unsure the correct passage of arguments without using .apply? Honest curiosity =)

Comment: Good architecture. Good interfaces, good validation; expectations are guaranteed. Apply() is good when you have a generic facade factory, where the factory doesn't know what's coming or going.

Here's an example of such a factory, lifted from abaaso:

https://gist.github.com/1406313